# Padding is visible when I press ctrl A

Tags: html, css, padding, margin

The problem is when I put padding on images with the links, the clickable area is this padding which I input. For example in this code:

```
        <a href="https://wikipedia.org"><img src="logo.svg" alt="canada1 logo" class="logo"></a>
        <nav id="language">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="https://wikipedia.org"><img src="img.svg" alt="canada logo"></li></a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section class="container">
            <img src="logo.svg" alt="casnada2 logo" class="logo1">
            <img src="img-bg.svg" alt="canada3" class="position">
    </section>
</body>
```

```
.logo {
    width: 207px;
    height: 29px;
    margin-left: 405px;
}
```

the link is clickable on whole margin left 405px, but I want it to be clickable only on logo area, how do I avoid this?

Comment: There is no padding shown here.

Comment: You have invalid html on the canada logo line. You are closing the li element before the anchor element

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack.

1st of all you have an html error in your `li`. You are closing your `a` after your `li` so you should close `li` after `a` to respect the opening order.

```
<li><a href="https://wikipedia.org"><img src="img.svg" alt="canada logo"></a></li>
```

You should just set your margin on your `a` element and not image.

By doing it this I saw that the image is totally stretching. So if you need to change the image it would be better to make it like 2nd demo. And setting max-width / height instead of width / height.

Such as below:

```css
.logo-link {     
  margin-left: 405px;
}
.logo{
  width: 207px;
  height: 29px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a class="logo-link" href="https://wikipedia.org"><img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/1cb/close-squirrel-1381764.jpg" alt="canada1 logo" class="logo"></a>
  <nav id="language">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="https://wikipedia.org"><img src="img.svg" alt="canada logo" /></a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

DEMO with image responsive.

```css
.logo-link {
  margin-left: 405px;

}
.logo{
  max-width: 207px;
  max-height: 29px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a class="logo-link" href="https://wikipedia.org"><img src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/1cb/close-squirrel-1381764.jpg" alt="canada1 logo" class="logo"></a>
  <nav id="language">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="https://wikipedia.org"><img src="img.svg" alt="canada logo" /></a></li>
      </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default entire content inside anchor tag () is clickble, try to put margins or padding at outer container like `<li> </li>` or `<a></a>`tag or you can also wrap  inside other tags.

```
.margin-class {     
  margin-left: 405px;
}
```

Place your class at

```
<a href="https://wikipedia.org" class="margin-class"><img src="logo.svg" alt="canada1 logo" class="logo"></a>
<nav id="language">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="https://wikipedia.org"><img src="img.svg" class="margin-class" alt="canada logo"></li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please provide code if you are attempting to answer the question. At the moment this would be better suited as a comment.

Comment: Thanks for commenting  lharby, added some code to explain what I mean by that

Answer (score 0):

You are giving margin to the image in a link. so it will take margin left but the width of its parent element that is `a` in this case, will take the full width including the width of image and the given margin. so you can just assign a class to the link and give it margin left. Here is how you can do it:

```css
a.logo-link {
  margin-left: 405px;
}
    
.logo {
  width: 207px;
  height: 29px;
}
```

```html
<a class="logo-link" href="https://wikipedia.org">
  <img src="logo.svg" alt="canada1 logo" class="logo">
</a>
```

Comment: Adding similar answer as existing answer is not welcome.

Comment: i didnt saw ur msg. the question was so simple i just saw the question and answered it

Comment: Check the question is good but check the existing answer is good too. If your answer way os very similar of an existing answer. No need to post it...

Comment: I am new so i dont know everything about stack overflow. i will be careful next time. sorry  ):

Comment: I know this is why I am telling you to pay attention. And if you think that an answer is a smarter than you would have done, you can also give upvote :)

Comment: Okay Thanks you so much  (: